# How to fill Datagridview in C# from DataTable adding custom columns?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I use the following code to bind `DataTable` with `DataGridView`:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
dt = serviceSqlite.select(new Pacients());    
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

I want to add custom columns in `dt` it should be one `CheckBox` and `Image`.

How to do that?

Comment: You can add them to your `DataGridView` like this `dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn());`

Comment: Can you share full example? With setting name of columns?

Comment: You can add columns to the table; add the 1st one a bool and the 2nd one as byte[] . Much more flexible when it comes to sorting or filtering..

Comment: @OPV OK. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them to your `DataGridView`. Like this:

```
var checkBox = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
{
    Name = "checkBox",
    HeaderText = @"checkBox",
    Width = 70
};
//Set other properties...
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkBox);
```

And same for `Image`:

```
DataGridViewImageColumn image = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
//....
```

Also if you want the new column to be appear in another column you can replace `dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkBox);` with following:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
var checkBox = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn
{
    Name = "checkBox",
    HeaderText = @"checkBox",
    Width = 70
};
//Set other properties...
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, checkBox);
```

And if you want to add it to your `DataTable` you can add it as `boolean` field in the `DataTable`:

```
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("checkBox", typeof(bool)));
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

So when you bind the `DataTable` to your `DataGridView`, a `CheckBoxColumn` is created for this `boolean` field.

Comment: After how to bind with DataTable?

Comment: I dont understand, I need to add new column to DataTable or to dataGridView1? Will it work correct? When one part of data from DataTable one added manually?

Comment: @OPV You need to add column to your `DataGridView` to show on your form. Just add my answer to your code and you will see the result.

Comment: @OPV, Pick your poison... Bind to your DataTable then, add a column to the DataGridView... Or... Add the column to your DataTable, then bind the DataGridView to your DataTable. The Global scope of your requirements should tell you which way to swing. Personally, I'd alter my DataTable, and then bind it to the DataGridView.

Comment: How can I change DataTable for new column CheckBox, I need to add empty column to DataTable? Can you edit your answer please

Comment: @OPV Also to add image to your `DataTable` it should be of type `byte[]` you can do like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15380361/2946329

Comment: How to set name for column: `new DataColumn("checkBox", typeof(bool))`?

Comment: I see that first parameter is name of column, and second parameters is Type. maybe second parameter should be 'Checkbox'

Comment: @OPV The second parameter should be `bool` so that the `DataGridView` will creates a `CheckBoxColumn` for this `boolean` field. And the first parameter is your arbitrary text that is used as `Name` and `HeaderText` of the column you can change it as you want.  You can change the `checkBox` text to what you want.

Comment: Thank you, last question, how to sort columns. if use `dt.Columns.Add` it addes to the end of datagridview.

Comment: `Insert` does not exist for `dt.Columns`